# Menu "stay hovered" after poiting to submenu

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, hover

When i point to main Menu i get my color:

[image: Hovered]

But when i point to submenu items, menu changes to default color instead of my one.

[image: No hover]

My CSS:

```
.menu:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #D5E7F8;
}

/* Tryed this, but doesn't work */
.context-menu:hover .menu {
    -fx-background-color: #D5E7F8;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu {
    -fx-background-color: #D5E7F8;
}
```

Is there any "event" like hover to set menu's color even when submenu pointed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
.menu:hover, .menu:showing {
    -fx-background-color: #D5E7F8 ;
}
```

do what you want?